# YouTube Player API hide play button, icons, & video title in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube video player API to embed a YouTube video in an iframe. I want to hide the play button, video title, and icons in the top right corner. This is working initially with the script I wrote below. However, once the video comes to an end the video looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of YouTube player API error]

None of the icons or the title are clickable either. Why do these appear once the video ends? How can I edit my script to hide the video title, play button, and the icons in the top right corner when the video ends?

Here is my script so far:

```
// download api code
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// this function creates an <iframe> and youtube player after the api code downloads
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '400',
    width: '800',
    playerVars: {
        'autoplay': 1,
        'controls': 0,
        'autohide': 1,
        'wmode': 'opaque',
        'rel': 0,
        'loop': 1
    },
    videoId: 'vlRxmgXPcW0',
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
});
}

// the api will call this function when the video player is ready
function onPlayerReady(event) {
event.target.mute();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As of September 25, 2018 the `showinfo` parameter has been
>   depreciated.
>   https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#august-23,-2018

Add `'showinfo' : 0,` to the constructor parameters

So:

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '400',
    width: '800',
    playerVars: {
        'autoplay': 1,
        'controls': 0, 
        'autohide': 1,
        'showinfo' : 0, // <- This part here
        'wmode': 'opaque',
        'rel': 0,
        'loop': 1
    },
    videoId: 'vlRxmgXPcW0',
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
});
```

As far as the play button, I don't believe you are allowed to hide that -- as its part of youtube's api branding terms of service.

Comment: Thank you! If I need to keep the play button, is there a way to make it work on hover? Currently, I cannot click on the button. Video function is visible at the bottom of http://pianopushplay.splashworldwide.com/

Comment: Well in that specific case you have `pointer-events: none;` on `.video-foreground` (meaning clicking wouldn't do anything anyway) as well as the `<section id="video" class="section section-center video-background">` is covering up the video (because of the `.video-background` class) so you aren't actually clicking the video -- you are clicking the `.video-background`